# Can i use Ext.MessageBox with Ext Core?

Tags: extjs, messagebox

I've used Ext JS in the past but i would now like to switch to Ext Core, becouse it can be load from Google CDN.

But now i'n trying to find out how to use Ext.MessageBox. Firefox says
 Ext.MessageBox is undefined

Is there any way to extend Ext Core with this or something?

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED ANSWER**

If you look through the Ext Core code *ext-core-debug.js*
you will notice that Ext.Message is not in the code so that is why it is undefined.

you will also need ext-base.js and ext-all.js (or ext-all-debug.js during the development phase)

NOTE: Ext Core contents are already within ext-all.js

Comment: Ext.core is actually a CORE of Ext functionality and you do need it. That's why it's bundled with ExtJS. It defines most basic classes like Element, Observable, Template or Ajax.  Apart from that, yup - Ext.Msg is part of ExtJS and not of Ext Core so you can't use it with Ext Core alone.

Comment: Seeing as you edited your message I'd like to clarify a bit: You don't in fact need file called `ext-core.js`. It's contents are already within `ext-all.js`. What I meant was that ExtJS library can not work without Ext Core classes.

Comment: Thanks, this is usefull information. I now use Ext for my Ajax calls. So i thing i have to convert them to jQuery ajax calls and use the jQuery UI dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use "ext-dev.js" or "ext-debug.js" and requires configuration, Example:

Ext.define.......
requires : ['Ext.window.MessageBox'],
.....

Is much faster.